# AppEngine Datastore Golang: Get ancestor for a query result

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to get the ancestor key for a query result? Based on the *datastore* documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.Run) the query.Run() result only has a Cursor() and a Next() function and neither will lead you to an ancestor. It seems like this should be information that's in scope, unless the mechanics of Datastore prevent it. Is it up to the developer to write the ancestor into a property (with a matching kind) on the child (if we're willing to incur the cost) for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query returns results, the ancestor is contained in the entity [`Key`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Key).

The entity key is returned by [`Iterator.Next()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Iterator.Next) for example:

```
func (t *Iterator) Next(dst interface{}) (*Key, error)
```

From the key, use the [`Key.Parent()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Key.Parent) method to get the ancestor.

See this example:

```
query := datastore.NewQuery("MyEntity")

e := MyEntity{}
for i := query.Run(ctx); ; {
    if k, err = t.Next(&te); err == nil {
        log.Infof("Ancestor / parent key: %v", k.Parent())
    }
}
```

---

Note that the ancestor is stored in the [`datastore.Query`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query), but it is not exported:

```
type Query struct {
    ancestor *Key
    // ...
}
```

And the [`datastore.Iterator`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Iterator) returned by [`Query.Run()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.Run) contains the `Query`, but it is also unexported:

```
type Iterator struct {
    // q is the original query which yielded this iterator.
    q *Query
    //...
}
```

So you can't access these struct fields, your best bet is an actual entity in the result (or rather its key).

Comment: Thanks. It actually looks like the only thing that writes to that is Ancestor() for the purpose of an outgoing query rather than a query result: https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/datastore/query.go#L118 . So, it isn't actually populated with anything that you don't already know.